# Why does accessing id work different on if and else in react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I basically started learning react-redux and I am in the middle of creating some simple store app. I would introduce my problem in a few bullet points.

1. I have got a basic store with some states and the Navbar where I have the Cart button.
2. After the click of the cart button, I want to open the cart list and rotate the Cart icon for 90deg.
3. I want to put everything in the one function and attach it to onClick()

my code looks like that: https://codepen.io/szygendaborys/pen/wZYZor?editors=0010

The main problem is that all works if I cancel the statement after else. That one:

```
    else {
    style = 'none';
    cartArrow.style.transform = 'rotate(0deg)'
    }
```

If I put back that statement, I receive an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null connected to

```
    cartArrow.style.transform = 'rotate(0deg)'
```

Can anyone help me and explain why the if statement works and else does not?

Comment: Do not use `getElementById()` in react instead change the style in your jsx render return, in the html so to say.

Comment: that would be quite a lot of code I think. Would not that impact the overall size of the project?

Comment: No it's exactly the same size: give your `<i id='cartArrow' className="fas fa-angle-right">` a style prop and pass the transform. Don't manipulate the dom directly via `getElementById` it's not the "react"-way of doing things.

Comment: let me just clarify, should it look like that then?

https://codepen.io/szygendaborys/pen/wZYZor?editors=0010

Comment: No you can manipulate your icon inline with either a different id/className or style prop, eg: `<i id={this.props.menuOpened ? 'cartArrow' :  'cartArrowDown'} className="fas fa-angle-right">`